# VS Code linter for html in blade.php files (unclosed tags detecting)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

I try to find a VS Code extension that detect unclosed tag in html tags but in blade.php files.

I tried to change files.associations in Settings like `"*.blade.php": "html"`, but it is not exact what I need. In that case I see an error about unclosed tag, but also html errors appear like "Doctype must be declared first" and "special characters must be escaped":
[editor screen when files.associations for blade set to "html"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aihsL.png)

When I remove

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.blade.php": "html"
},
```

from settings.json and blade files associate with Blade - no errors detects at all, though the unclosed tag is still present: [editor screen with files.associations for blade set to blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lejd.png)

I could not find such extension, that correctly lints html in blade. Maybe there is build-in ability to fix it?

A tip about how to set html linter more flexible and stop throwing errors about doctype and escaping of ">" is fine for me too.

Hope for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No. I’ve put aside this problem. I still use blade as blade because errors are annoying in html mode.